# Windows CE application Crashes

Tags: windows-ce, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6

I have an application that is written for windows mobile 6.0. Now the company moved the same application to windows ce Motorola MC32N0 .The application [image]
   works fine for most of the time. Sometimes it crashes.

I don't know  why this is happening. i am really stuck in this.Any help would be appreciated.It is a very big project. so i am not posting  any code.

sometime in the error log i hva the error

Can't find PInvoke DLL 'rfidapi32.dll'.
System.MissingMethodException: Can't find PInvoke DLL 'rfidapi32.dll'. In the reference the dll syMbol.RFID3.Device  is already added.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your CE image is missing a dll or, at least, an entry point inside it.
What you reference in .NET is a wrapper that links the DLL at runtime, so using it is not enough, if the DLL is not there (or it's a different one) it will not work.
Check that the DLL is inside the \Windows folder or inside one of the folders referenced in the
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Loader] SystemPath 
registry entry.

Comment: How do i check this. This is first time i  am working on windows mobile device.

Comment: Please do not mix Windows Mobile and Windows CE terms! The device seems to be a Windows CE7 device. These normally have a start menu and a programs folder with a file explorer that you can use to look for the DLL (enable show all files or 'do not hide system files' or whaever it is called). Such SDKs (I assume a motorola SDK) come normally with runtime files that need to be installed prior to use device specific functions.

Comment: I have installed my project on windows\programs\Abc\ my.exe and copied all the  .dll for the exe on the same folder

Comment: You should have a file manager on your device or a command prompt. But this may depend on the way the vendor customized it.
If you have remote debugging support via Visual Studio you can use remote tools to browse the filesystem and also edit the registry.